# What does this openweather error "25.00 square degrees" mean

Tags: openweathermap

I am trying to identify the cause of this openweathermap api error. I could not find any references in the documentation.

This request is a SUCCESS:

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/box/city?bbox=-96.8466%2C37.0905747%2C-92.5829684%2C41.7686%2C9&appid=<apikey>
```

While this request FAILS

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/box/city?bbox=-96.5829684%2C26.5383355%2C-79.37923649999999%2C41.0905747%2C9&appid=<apikey>
```

response

```
{"cod":"400","message":"Requested area is larger than allowed for your account type (25.00 square degrees)"}
```

I know it has something to do with the bbox range, but I can't find any documentation. I am currently testing with the free subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically means that you are fetching an area larger than what the free subscription area allows. A 25°² area means a region between 4 lat/lng position that is covering 25 degrees, for example :

```
An area ranging from 75 to 70 degrees North, and 0 to 5 degrees East (5x5° = 25°)
75°N,0°E ---- 75°N,5°E



70°N,0°E ---- 75°N,5°E
```

Comment: That makes sense. I just found out that they have added this limitation to the free and startup plans.  Hopefully the documentation will be updated soon.